# d3.js - why would dragging using d3.zoom() cause jitteriness when calling transform to svg itself?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

There are two forked jsFiddle examples that I created.

https://jsfiddle.net/publicst/pfjg1025/1/

https://jsfiddle.net/publicst/pfjg1025/3/

The only difference is the existence of `canvas` and `zoomed()` function calling `svg.attr("transform"` vs `canvas.attr("transform"`.

However, the second example with svg.attr jitters a lot when you drag any of the area.

Why could this be?